# Are Command Prompt and PowerShell terminal emulators?

Tags: windows, powershell, terminal, command-line-interface

I have read in Codecademy that

> To access the command line, we use a terminal emulator, often just
> called the terminal.

This gave me the impression that PowerShell and Command Prompt are terminal emulators but when I checked the list of terminal emulators for windows I found the following [list in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_terminal_emulators#Microsoft_Windows). I would really appreciate it if anyone can help me understand what terminal emulators are, what PowerShell and Command Prompt are, How these things are different. Thank you!

Comment: powershell.exe and cmd.exe are console host applications. The Windows Console Host historically doesn't implement [PTY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoterminal?wprov=sfla1), and isn't considered a "true" terminal emulator. For the purpose of "accessing the command line", ie. run command line applications, the distinction doesn't matter much

Comment: Hi @MathiasR.Jessen, Thanks for the comment. Could you tell what's the difference between console host app and pseudoterminal? I am a beginner and it all seem similar to me.

Answer (score 4):

[**Terminal *emulators***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator) are applications that emulate the behavior of [character-oriented *hardware* terminals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_terminal#Character-oriented_terminal) from the early days of computing. For all practical purposes, the **[Windows *Console*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Console)** is an instance of a terminal emulator, as is its modern successor, **[Windows Terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Terminal)**.

Typically, the applications that run inside these emulators are **interactive [*shells*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_(computing))**<sup>[1]</sup> such as PowerShell and `cmd.exe`, which act as [command-line interpreters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Command-line_interpreter), which enable running other applications as well as commands built into those shells and scripts written for those shells.

---

<sup>[1] On Windows, somewhat confusingly, the term *shell* is also used for [the *graphical* (GUI) shell that provides the Windows desktop and File Explorer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_shell). Overall, however, the term *shell* usually refers to terminal-, character-based shells, such as the POSIX-like shells in the Unix world (a prominent example of which is Bash), and to PowerShell on Windows, as its name implies; while the term conceptually also applies to `cmd.exe`, historically it hasn't been used much in that context.</sup>